# Issues with algorithm to merge adjacent rectangles

Tags: java, algorithm, merge

I'm working on a program that tracks and identifies a reflective target with a webcam. Part of the problem is there could be multiple reflective sources of noise in the scene.

I've devised a system that created and stored small rectangles based on light areas as such (blue rectangles are what my code has generated):

[image]

Now I need to basically need to merge the adjacent dark blue rectangles into one rectangle to form the light sources in the scene so I can do further analysis (in this case 2 light sources so 2 different rectangles).

My code for that merging operation is below: (Where `lo.polygon` is an ArrayList containing my dark blue `Rectangles`)

```
       for (int i = 0; i < lo.polygon.size(); i++) {
            Rectangle r0 = lo.polygon.get(i);
            for (int n = i + 1; n < lo.polygon.size(); n++) {
                Rectangle r1 = lo.polygon.get(n);
                if (r0.intersects(r1)) {
                    int x0 = Math.min(r0.x, r1.x);
                    int y0 = Math.min(r0.y, r1.y);
                    int w = Math.max(r0.x + r0.width, r1.x + r1.width) - x0;
                    int h = Math.max(r0.y + r0.height, r1.y + r1.height) -y0;
                    lo.polygon.set(i, new Rectangle(x0, y0, w, h));
                    lo.polygon.remove(n);
                    i=0;
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue is, this code doesn't seem to be working very well. Even without the noise, it seems to work only sometimes. Here is an example of it working, and doing what I intend (where the light blue rectangle is the merged one):

[image]

Here are examples of it absolutely failing:

[image]

[image]

What is happening? Is my merge logic flawed? Please help! Thanks.

**Edit:** I realize OFC that this will have some inaccuracies even when its working. For example in the second example I gave of it failing, the rotated target has MOSTLY the correct bounding box I'd expect the algorithm to create. However, it needs to be taller (as the top right corner is not contained within it) and the noise is incorrectly split into two rectangles.

**Edit 2:** I forgot to mention, I increase the bounds of all the dark blue rectangles by 2 from what you actually see in the image so that they intersect nicely and I can use the `intersects()` method, not just touch at edges. Also, the list is in order by columns top down.

**Edit 3:** another failed example case (with numerical data)

these are the generated light blue rectangles:

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=270,y=288,width=213,height=98]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=296,y=144,width=238,height=106]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=270,y=288,width=230,height=108]
```

[image]

Comment: @TedHopp I didn't get a chance to read that.

Comment: That's because my answer was completely off. I missed that you were setting `i` back to 0 whenever you merged rectangles.

Comment: @TedHopp oh yeah xD sorry I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that `Rectangle#intersects` only tests that the interiors of the rectangles overlap. I don't believe that it checks whether the rectangles share a boundary.

Comment: @TedHopp oh yes I forgot to mention. I increase the bounds of all the rectangles so that they intersect. Thanks for pointing that out. See appropriate edit.

Comment: Hm. Don't see what the problem is. Do you have sample data for a specific case that fails?

Comment: @TedHopp what type of sample data are you looking for? See in the question body under the fails section.

Comment: I'm asking if you have the actual x, y, width, and height values for each rectangle of an array that fails to merge properly.

Comment: @TedHopp i can get that fairly easily. Give me a minute I'll collect some data.

Comment: @maraca - Ashwin is trying to go back to recheck intersections for rectangles that may have been disjoint before the merge but now overlap. Removing `i = 0;` will definitely not fix Ashwin's problem and will, in fact, make things worse.

Comment: @maraca in order to not skip cases because it reindexes.

Comment: Yes I saw it, what you need to do is `n--;` instead of `i = 0;`.

Comment: @maraca - No, that's not enough, because the merge may cause the new rectangle (which replaced the rectangle at index `i`) to overlap an earlier rectangle. Think of merging two legs of an L; the merged rectangle may now intersect a rectangle that poked in at the top right but intersected neither leg individually.

Comment: @maraca - Consider these three rectangles: A: (x:0, y:0, w:3, h:3); B: (x:0, y:5, w: 10, h: 5); C: (x:5, y:0, w:5, h:10). If you sort them first by x and then by y, then they are ordered as (A, B, C). A intersects neither B nor C. However, B and C intersect and their union intersects A. Same thing happens if you sort first by y and then by x, which orders them as (A, C, B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are skipping the first rectangle whenever you merge the last two rectangles of the array. The inner loop exits and the outer loop then increments `i`. Since you just set `i` to 0, that will cause the first rectangle to never be considered again.

As a solution, replace this line:

```
i = 0;
```

with this:

```
i = -1;
break;
```

There are probably more efficient ways to do the looping, but this will certainly fix the skipping problem. Then you can try introducing more clever indexing techniques.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much, I've been debugging for like 2 hours.Works great now. I feel like a complete moron. What a dumb mistake. I swear im better then that ;)

Comment: As for clever techniques, the array is actually in order of collumns top down, so you are probably correct. I just wanted to get this simple way working first. TY